# CakePHP how to pass get params from GET form like index/valueOfTheParam?

Tags: php, cakephp

I would like add search form into index page,  after the click on the button should be called url in format

```
index/valueOfTheParam
```

I tried to do by passing GTE params, but it inserting char

```
?
```

Into URL.

How the form should be in the right way please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: If you submit form vi GET request then the param will add in url with QueryStrings. if you want to add those param in url like `www.host.com/index/param1` then you may write a simple script code

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible in CakePHP way?

Comment: you can pass param both way by client side and CakePHP can handle both types of data

Comment: But it is based on the JavaScript, i have not problem with JS solution, but i would like to use native way using PHP (CakePHP).

Comment: Could You please add an Example how to do it in the CakePHP way?